# postgres/sqlalchemy/python: converting sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select to sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query?

Tags: python, memory, sqlalchemy

I'm working on an existing application that runs SQL postgres queries by creating `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select` objects and running their `execute()` method.

I'm trying to reduce the client-side memory use of these queries, and so I'd like to convert this to a session-based methodology using `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query` objects upon which I could use the `yield_per()` method to cut down on the amount of data which is sent from the server to the client.

In order to do so, I'd like to somehow convert the `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select` objects directly into `sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query` objects, so that I don't have to rewrite all of the existing queries in the various places in the code where they currently exist.

I haven't been able to find any way to perform this conversion. Does such a conversion capability even exist in sqlalchemy, and if so, where can I find documentation for it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sorta-kinda convert statements to `Query` objects like this:

```
stmt = select([foo.c.id, foo.c.bar])
query = session.query(*stmt.inner_columns).from_statement(stmt)
```

But this is the wrong way to go, because you're going up a layer into the ORM without using any of the ORM features. It's more correct to figure out how to do this at the Core layer instead. The correct way to do this is with [`stream_results`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.stream_results):

```
conn = engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True)
for row in conn.execute(stmt):
    ...
```

This uses `BufferedRowResultProxy` to buffer results, which has logic to fetch successively larger batches capped at 1000. If you need to change this behavior, you'll need to drop down to the DBAPI layer:

```
conn = engine.connect()
with conn.connection.connection.cursor(name="foo") as cur:
    cur.itersize = 10000
    compiled = stmt.compile(engine)
    cur.execute(compiled.string, compiled.params)
    for row in cur:
        pass
```

Comment: OK. I see that I can stay with `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select` as long as I use `stream_results=True`. Is it true that the following is equivalent to your cursor-based example? ... `conn = engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True, max_row_buffer=10000)`

Comment: @HippoMan `stream_results=True` is mostly equivalent to `connection.cursor(name="foo")` in terms of memory usage behavior, except that `stream_results=True` fetches exponentially growing batch sizes, whereas the DBAPI cursor fetches fixed (`itersize`) batches. You should see no difference in almost all use cases.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.